# Confidence interval for the distance between two CDF

Tags: probability, confidence-interval, cumulative-distribution-function, asymptotics

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two real random variables with cumulative distribution functions $F_X$ and $F_Y$, respectively.

Define $d = \sup(F_X(x) - F_Y(x))$. If $\hat F_X$ and $\hat F_Y$ are empirical versions of $F_X$ and $F_Y$ respectively, then an estimator of $d$ is $\hat d = \sup(\hat F_X(x) - \hat F_Y(x))$

Does anyone know how to build a confidence interval for $d$ based on $\hat d$?

Comment: This looks like the test statistic of the Kolmogorov Smirnov test for the equality of two distributions . So check the derivation. The confidence interval will be the acceptance region of the test.

Comment: K-S acceptance region is constructed under the assumption that $F_X = F_Y$. I don't know how to take into consideration the possible inequality of the cdf's

Comment: Are you looking for one number to quantify the distance between two CDFs or a whole confidence region where you allow for some uncertainty at every point along the CDF?

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a confidence interval by [bootstrap sampling](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-05-introduction-to-probability-and-statistics-spring-2014/readings/MIT18_05S14_Reading24.pdf)

First sample from your empirical distributions $X$ and $Y$ to generate populations of CDFs $\left\{(\hat F_X)_1,\dots,(\hat F_X)_n\right\}$ and $\left\{(\hat F_Y)_1,\dots,(\hat F_Y)_n\right\}$

Next sample pairs of these CDFs to compute a population of bootstrap estimates of $\hat d$: $\left\{\hat d_1,\dots,\hat d_m\right\} = \left\{\sup\left((\hat F_X)_{i_1}-(\hat F_Y)_{j_1}\right),\dots,\sup\left((\hat F_X)_{i_m}-(\hat F_Y)_{j_m}\right)\right\}$

Then compute the differences between these bootstrap estimates $\hat d_*$ and the true $\hat d$: $\{\delta_1,\dots,\delta_m\} = \{\hat d_1 - \hat d,\dots,\hat d_m - \hat d\}$

And finally construct your $\alpha$ confidence interval: $\left[\hat d-\delta_{\lceil m\cdot(1-\alpha/2)\rceil}, \hat d-\delta_{\lfloor m\cdot\alpha /2 \rfloor }\right]$

This construction is equivalent to the [pivot confidence interval](http://www2.stat.duke.edu/~banks/111-lectures.dir/lect13.pdf)

Note that you will need to make your numbers of samples $n$ and $m$ sufficiently large for this confidence interval to be reliable.